# "cat" command killed when reading from a Linux device driver

Tags: linux, device-driver

I have an assignment in my Operating Systems class to make a simple pseudo-stack Linux device driver. So for an example, if I was to write "Hello" to the device driver, it would return "olleH" when I read from it. We have to construct a tester program in C to just call upon the read/write functions of the device driver to just demonstrate that it functions in a FILO manner. I have done all of this, and my tester program, in my opinion, demonstrates the purpose of the assignment; however, out of curiosity, inside BASH I execute the following commands:

**echo "Test" > /dev/driver**

**cat /dev/driver**

where /dev/driver is the special file I created using "mknod". However, when I do this, I get a black screen full of errors. After I swap back to the GUI view using CNTRL+ALT+F7, I see that BASH has returned "Killed".

Does anyone know what could be causing this to happen? I am confused since my tester program calls open(), read(), and write() with everything functioning as it should.

If I need to show some code, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your device driver that writes to the buffer you are providing it is most likely causing this issue.

To debug, you can do the following:

- First, make sure the read part is fine. You can `printk` your internal buffer after you read from input to ensure this.
- Second, in your write function, `printk` some information instead of actually writing anything and make sure everything is fine.

Also, make sure the writer makes it clear that the write has ended. I'm not particularly sure about device drivers, but you either need to return 0 as the number of bytes written when called a second time, or set an eof variable (if that is one of the arguments to your function)

Comment: I'm looking into this now... the example we were given in class only returned the bytes_read or bytes_written depending on the function. The way I understand it, when the bytes_read is 0, the read is done. I have mine set to do this, but something apparently isn't right.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to use printk and see what was going on. Apparently I needed an extra boolean test in my read function. My read position in the buffer was going out of bounds. But its fixed now. Thanks again!

Comment: @StayPuff, no problem. Kernel bugs can get really **really** nasty. Only way I can personally actually debug is to print out stuff and fail. Check the log to see if its fine so far and if it was, move the log further ahead. Very cumbersome!